# periodic update of cache in hibernate in a web application

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, servlets, ehcache

I'm fetching data using Hibernate from three tables. Out of which, table1 get updated rarely(once in a week) and table2&table3 frequently(once in 8 hours). I'm doing only read operations of these data in my web application. 
I want to update the cache in background for these objects with 1 day frequency for table1 and 1hour frequency for table2&table3. How can I achieve this using Hibernate, servlets?

Comment: Have you measured that the queries to these tables caused a performance problem in your app? If not, just don't use a cache. Your application will be simpler and easier to scale.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using level-2 cache? You can setup Timers or schedule tasks with thread-pools. Have the code that the timer executes use Hibernate's Cache api (exposed from Session) to invalidate various level-2 caches.

Comment: No need to use a timer. Decent second-level cache implementations have a time-to-live configuration.

Comment: True. Check out EhCache or Infinispan for second-tier caches.

Comment: I have configured level-2 cache using EHCache but when i'm hitting the submit button from my webpage, it's going for a database hit. How do I need to manage the cache configuration in java class.

Comment: Level-2 cache only works when retrieving by Primary Key (or populating a referenced entity {lazy-loading} where PK is known). To test if you have EhCache configured properly, open hibernate session, retrieve by pk, close. Then open, retrieve and close again. If you see a second SQL something is wrong.